# How to extract data from PHP object

Tags: php, arrays, object

I need to extract data from a crypto API and I am using this PHP code

```
  $url = 'https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms=BTC,ETH&tsyms=USD,EUR';
  $data = file_get_contents($url);
  $priceInfo = json_decode($data);

foreach ($priceInfo as $key ){
foreach ($key as $vala => $valb ){
    echo "<br> $vala--> $valb " ;
}
}
```

which is returning this

```
USD--> 49463.82 
EUR--> 40802.62 
USD--> 1630.65 
EUR--> 1345.66
```

How should I change the code to show this ?

```
BTC USD--> 49463.82 
BTC EUR--> 40802.62 
ETH USD--> 1630.65 
ETH EUR--> 1345.66
```

The array $priceInfo return this

```
stdClass Object ( [BTC] => stdClass Object ( [USD] => 49432.16 [EUR] => 40773.08 ) [ETH] => stdClass Object ( [USD] => 1628.21 [EUR] => 1343.67 ) )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the key of the first loop.

```php
foreach ($priceInfo as $crypto => $obj ){
foreach ($obj as $cur => $val ){
    echo "<br>$crypto $cur--> $val " ;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use $key's value as below

```
foreach ($priceInfo as $key ){
  foreach ($key as $vala => $valb ){
      echo "<br>$key $vala--> $valb " ;
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$priceInfo = json_decode($data, true);
var_dump($priceInfo);
```

later do with this array wha you need